# Determine the role domain the function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Determine the domain of the function $f(x) = c \tan x + 2 c \tan 2x + 4 c \tan 4x+ 8c \tan 8x +....$ ($n$ terms)

Are there any hint for me to proceed with this problem?

Comment: What precisely is _role domain_?

Comment: @AndrewChin edited

Comment: @Behemooth Edit the title also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ has $n$ terms, we have that
$$f(x)=c\tan x+2c\tan 2x+\cdots +2^{n-1}c\tan 2^{n-1}x.$$

Recall that the domain of $\tan$ is
$$\displaystyle\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \left((2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2},(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right),$$
that is, in order to obtain $\tan x$, we need that
$$(2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}<x<(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$$
for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus, given $m\in \mathbb{N}$, in order to obtain $\tan mx$, we need that
$$(2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}<mx<(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2},$$
which implies
$$(2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2m}<x<(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2m},$$
for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that the larger $m$, the smaller the intervals where $x$ is ranging.

Hence, if $x$ is in the domain of $f$, then $x$ must be in the domain of $\tan mx$ for all $m=1,2,4,\ldots,2^{n-1}$. Since $2^{n-1}$ is the biggest, the corresponding interval is the smallest, therefore it is inside all the other intervals. It implies that
$$(2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2^n}<x<(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2^n},$$
for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, which means that the domain of $f$ is the union of all the intervals of that form, that is,
$$\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\left((2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2^n},(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right).$$
Actually, the domain of $f$ is contained in this set, because when we take this union, we end up including all the extremals of the other intervals corresponding to $m=1,2,4,\ldots,2^{n-2}$. Therefore, we have to get rid off those points too. If we do that, we get all the real line, except the points of the form $\frac{k\pi}{2^n}$, that is, the domains of $f$ is
$$\mathbb{R}\setminus \left\{\frac{k\pi}{2^n};\ k\in \mathbb{Z},\ k\neq 0\right\}.$$

Comment: It looks to me like the OP is adding (multiples of) tangent terms of *powers* of two times $x.$ [rather than multiples of 2 times $x.$] So the highest would be $2^{n-1}c \tan 2^{n-1}x$

Comment: You are right, @coffeemath . I have edited my answer. I reasoned as $2^{n-1}$ but wrote as $2(n-1)$. Thanks for the comment.